# PhantomJS - Can't click the form button

Tags: javascript, button, phantomjs

I can't click the button using PhantomJS. Filling text boxes work perfectly. I want to use pure js (no jquery). Ideas?

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://www.somepage.com/login', function(status) {
console.log(">page loaded");

page.render('page.png');

page.evaluate(function () {
    var username = "";
    var password = "";
    document.getElementById('login-input').value = username; //works
    document.getElementById('passwd').value = password; //works
    document.getElementsByName('login_button').click(); //this doesn't click the button
});

console.log(">form submitted");

page.render('page1.png');

phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to trigger function in following code `x.click();` after the click function as follows.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("btn");
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', function() {

  console.log("Clicked !!");

})

x.click();
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```